# How to open remote html file in internet explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to open a remote html file in IE 8. Interestingly, there is no error thrown and the remote file is not opened in IE 8. Below is command executed on hamilton shell prompt:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86) \\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" "file://o|\\portsrc\\spg\\system_1\\help\\creo_help_pma/usascii/pma/simulation_modules/modstr/constrnt/reference/insuf_cons_models.html"
```

But, the file gets opened in firefox:

```
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "file://o|\\portsrc\\spg\\system_1\\help\\creo_help_pma/usascii/pma/simulation_modules/modstr/constrnt/reference/insuf_cons_models.html"
```

Please guide me for the same.

Regards,
Amol Gaikwad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer and below is the solution to open the remote file in Internet explorer.

"C:\Program Files (x86) \Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "file:///o|/portsrc/spg/system_1/help/creo_help_pma/usascii/pma/simulation_modules/modstr/constrnt/reference/insuf_cons_models.html"

Resolved using "file:///" instead of "file://".

And 2nd the most important a network html path.

Changed slashes from '\\' to '/'.

Thanks,
Amol.